# How do I make a Rows x Cols grid of individual instances

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, processing

I have a class `Box` that represents one single box of a grid. Now, I'm trying to create a Rows x Cols grid of instances of the boxes.

I would like to have a 2d `ArrayList` of boxes. Something analogous to the array: `coord[rows][cols]`. So that when I write `coord.get(5)(6)`, I'm getting the box that is at row `5` and column `6`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList of ArrayLists. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Box>> grid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Box>>();
grid.add(new ArrayList<Box>());
grid.get(0).add(new Box());
Box myBox = grid.get(0).get(0);
```

But note that this is pretty gross. Just use a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of Box, even a 2D (or 3D, 4D, ...) of Box:

```
Box[][] boxes = new Box[ROWS][COLS];
```

instead of

```
coord.get(5)(6);
```

you simply write

```
Box b = boxes[5][6];
```